# Tomcat 8 problems on download files from browser

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

I have two servers, apache tomcat 7 and apache tomcat 8, on tomcat 7 it's all ok, but on tomcat 8 a problem happens, when I click on generate .xlsx file, of error page 404, but the file is generated, pressing f5 on the error page the file is downloaded.

Button to generate excel file

[image]

File generated but not downloaded

[image]

The Mime types are ok, i make a copy from tomcat7
**Remembering that the same application on the tomcat 7 server works perfectly.**

Comment: Do you generate the file dynamically and write it to the filesystem, or do you generate the file dynamically and stream it back to the client with that single URL?

Comment: The file is created on server folder dynamically, i dont understand why works on tomcat 7 and not on tomcat 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomcat 8 changed the way that file-caching works. I suspect you need to tweak some of your configuration to account for that. Have a look at the [resources section of the Tomcat configuration guide](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/resources.html) for how to configure the caching.

Remember that Tomcat will cache a "not found" file-lookup just as well as a "found" file-lookup under normal circumstances.

Comment: Very Tanks, i have to disabled cache on context.xml! on tomcat7 does not exist this configuration!